# How do I get a column from a sub query?

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent

I have a `reports` table which I have to join with `report_locations` table to find reports that are within certain distance of its tagged_location, which is store in `report_locations` table.

I have the following code below

```
$reports = Report::join('report_locations', function ($report_locations) use ($lat, $lng, $filter, $distance) {
            if ($lat != 0 && $lng != 0 && strtolower($filter) == 'location' && $distance != 0) { // Search based on location if lat, lng is not 0 and filter is set to location
                $report_locations->on('report_locations.report_id', '=', 'reports.id')
                    ->select(DB::raw(' (6371 * acos (cos (radians(' . $lat . ')) * cos (radians (lat)) * cos (radians (lng) - radians (' . $lng . ')) + sin (radians (' . $lat . ')) * sin (radians (lat)))) 
                            AS distance WHERE distance <= ' . $distance));
            }
        })->get();
```

It returns the columns of both `reports` and `report_locations`, but it does not return the `distance` column which I created using `select` inside the sub query on `join`

How do I make the query return the `distance` value that I created inside the sub query?

Comment: Perhaps adding an alias... like  ` something as column_name`?

Comment: It does have an alias, I have `AS distance` inside the select query within the sub query

Comment: Ah yeah you're right... Have you tried to include the needed columns in the `get()` function? . i.e for example `->get(['reports.*', 'report_locations.*', 'report_locations.distance'])` or use select?

Comment: Yes I did. Even if I simply select all with `select('*')`, distance does not appear

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using Eloquent relationships for this?

Comment: Might you need to return the `$report_locations` query results within closure.